# Folder writing permission

Tags: php, file, permissions, directory

If I'm not wrong, to create or delete a file from a directory, you either need write permissions on that folder or write permission on that file (in case you're modifying it).
So, in a folder with 711 permissions and a php script (in that folder) with 755 permissions, and the following code:

```
$fileName = "createdFile.txt";
$fileHandle = fopen($fileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fclose($fileHandle);
```

Should this create a new file or throw an error? I have tried this on the public_html folder of a webserver and it does work, which surprises me because of what I have mentioned.

Moreover, I'm kind of confused about permissions for "everyone" in the case of the webserver. If you have 777 permissions on a folder, but no php script that could actually write or move files to that folder, is there any risk at all? Or would it have to be ftp access or some php script?

Sorry for the confusing question. I'll try to clarify if I can.

Comment: Could you do an `ls -l` on the file that's been created by this script and also post up whether you're running this script via the webserver.

Comment: I'm running the script through the webserver (public url, that is). I can't run that command since it's a shared server, but the file permissions are 755.

Comment: The created file has `755` set or the parent folder is `755`

Comment: see my updated comment below.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. The folder containing the file has 711 permission and the file 755 permissions, which strikes me as odd since it can create the file with no problem.

Comment: I think the issue is that the 'owner' is set to '7' meaning the owner as rw+x permissions. If that php script is running as the user that is the owner of the file or folder then it's '7' not 1 or 5 or 6 or anything but all access 7(read write execute)

Comment: But the user is "everyone" and not the owner. I've tried picking up a file without 777 access and it won't work.

Comment: I sorry, I don't understand. I feel that you may not understand how this type of file system works and may be comparing it to the NTFS(Windows) file system which is different is several ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to give a much better answer because of the limited info about the created file you're able to supply but I'm presuming that the server is running as the same user that you upload files as. This is the only explanation that I have about it being able to create a file in a directory that has `755` permissions.

I'd have a chat with your hosting provider or check their documentation to verify in case there's some kind of misconfiguration on their part.

Comment: While this looks right like the issue, I can't see files that doesn't have R permission on the "everyone" group, so I can presume that it *is* actually running as "everyone" instead of that user.

Answer (score 2):

755 is read and execute not write
You would need write permissions 766 or 777

OK, a little more help. It's a safe bet that the user account that the php script is running under owns the folder and since the first digit is a '7' the 'owner' has read write and execute permissions.

Comment: The user explained that in the `755` directory they were able to create a file using the code snippet.

Comment: I know and I explained that he would need 766 or 777 to do that. Sorry I wasn't clear enough to make you happy.

Comment: @James C I have edited the above comment to hopefully make it a bit clearer. I apologize as I assumed this would get sorted after he realized that it should not happen as that was his actual question.

Comment: That was indeed my question, although I'm wondering the reason why it does work in these conditions and not under a 'W' allowed permission.

Comment: See above. I believe this is an issue of 'owner' not permissions.